# How to navigate to previous page in selenium ide

Tags: selenium, ide

I am trying to navigate to previous page and click on a link using Selenium Ide. I tried
execute script history.back()
execute script window.history.go(-1)
Both the commands work, but am not able to click on the link that is available in the previous window.Don’t know where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

```java
WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();
.
.
.
driver.navigate().back();
driver.findElement(<locator>).click();
```

Comment: In my company they don’t use selenium webdriver. They use selenium ide . That’s the problem. I know webdriver commands. I need help with Selenium Ide

Answer (score 0):

In the **command** section, look for :

> run script

And in the **Target** section, type :

> window.history.go(-1)

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, I worked around the same issue by saving the URL path to a variable and passing the variable to the `open` command, instead of using `window.history`.

Comment: Yeah. I did this and it worked. Thanks Matt